# Why React can't reach Flask endpoints in production?

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, flask-cors

I've got a React app with Flask on the backend in production and I found out
that none of my endpoints are reached from React.

I'm aware that when using client-side routing developer needs to use a catch-all function
similar to the below:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def error_handler(e):
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I'm using Flask-CORS to handle cross origin requests:

within config.py:

```
class ProductionConfig:
    CORS_HEADERS = 'Content-Type'
    ...
    ...
```

my blueprint:

```
CORS(auth_blueprint, resources={r'/*': {"origins": "https://example.com", "allow_headers": "*", "expose_headers": "*"}})

@auth_blueprint.route('/auth/login', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def login():
    ...
    ...
```

on the frondend I'm defining headers like this:

```
const headers = { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" };
const url = "https://example.com:5000/auth/login";
axios.post(url, data, headers).then(resp => { ... })
```

And I'm not getting any errors whatsoever. Server's logs are clean and the console only shows `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com:5000/auth/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`.
"Reason: CORS request did not succeed" means that the server didn't return anything.
The app renders fine however React (axios) can't reach my endpoints. Are there any gotchas I'm not aware of ? When request is sent I'm not even getting a status code in the network tab.

Thank you.

**Screenshot of the network tab:**

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You need to change the connection protocol to `http`.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Besides https is a standard.

Comment: No, it have matter. Specially if you working on your local PC and, of course does not have certificate.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541547/does-cross-origin-resource-sharingcors-differentiate-between-http-and-https/19542686#19542686

Comment: Sorry you're right in that case. My production server uses encryption.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of your network tab of browser dev. toolkit?

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: From the looks of it only POST requests are troubling.